# How I pack int16 into bytes in python

Tags: python, int, byte

I want pack int to a bytes string in python, like this: pack 29 into '\x1d\x00'.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `struct` module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack( "<H", 29 )
'\x1d\x00'
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) for an explanation of the format characters. Here's a summary of the relevant parts:

The character `'H'` means an unsigned short.

`'<'` is a prefix character specifying size, byte order and alignment.

Size, for our purposes, means how many bits an unsigned short actually is. With "standard sizes", specified with any of `'<'`, `'='`, `'!'`, or `'>'`, this is 16 bits. With '@' (which is the default), the size is implementation-defined (though for unsigned short, it's still pretty *likely* to be 16 bits).

Byte order means whether the most significant bytes come first or last in the byte sequence. Most-significant first is called "big-endian" and is specified with `'>'`; `struct.pack( ">H", 29)` is `'\x00\x1d'`. Least-significant first is called "little-endian", and is what is shown in your example -- `29` encodes to `'\x1d\x00'`.

(Alignment is irrelevant for our purposes since we're only packing a single element.)

Comment: A little clarification: all these are standard sizes and alignment but vary in order: `=`: native order; `<`: little endian; `>`: big endian. Additionally `@`: native size, order and alignment.